# jQuery loads only certain part of page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I know this is asked 1000x on this website but I cant get it to work.

I want to get the table information from this website with the current style:
https://webuntis.a12.nl/WebUntis/?school=roc%20a12#Timetable?type=1&departmentId=0

So I tried this ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/P77Ev/43/)):

```
<div id="wrap"></div>
<script>
    $.get('https://webuntis.a12.nl/WebUntis/?school=roc%20a12#Timetable?type=1&departmentId=0', function(data) {
        var wrap = $('#mainTable', $(data));
    });
</script>
```

But it wont do anything. Perhaps it can be done with PHP?

Comment: it looks like a cross domain request.... in that case it will not work

Comment: then please tell me how do i get the table information then? or is it not possible?

Comment: if it is cross domain, it doesn't look like possible

Comment: hmm oke there is a ics file available can i display thad on my website??

Comment: one possible solution is to implement a proxy like solution in your server like PHP

Comment: If your JavaScript doesn't work, then **read the error console** in your browser. It will often tell you why.

Comment: Pass the URL to your server, and get that to load the page and return it... http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a cross domain security issue.
You are basicaly not allowed to do requests from one domain to another.
What you could do is putting everything inside an iframe

```
<body>
<html>
this is my page
< iframe src="https://webuntis.a12.nl/WebUntis/?school=roc%20a12#Timetable?   type=1&departmentId=0" height=500 width=500></iframe>
</html>
</body>
```

Another option could be a server site scraper. Its a bit more complex, but what it does is basicaly making a copy of that specific url and stores it on server to be served from your domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl()` function to get all the contents of that page. Store its response in a variable, use regular expression to extract all the data inside `div id=timetable` (This div contain the table you are looking for)

Comment: oke so do you perhaps have a full tutorial of that process?

Comment: you can refer this two links and I am sure can do it then:
http://extract-web-data.com/scraping-in-php-with-curl/
http://toolspot.org/extract-website-data.php

Comment: Go to section "The Whole Scraper Listing" on the first link, it is exactly doing the same thing.